# What do I need to make a LP-E12 Coupler be powered by either a 18650 or 14500 lition battery?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries

So I'm working on a Battery Grip for my Canon M50 Camera which uses an LP-E12 Battery which operates on 7.2V. I found a battery coupler for it that has a 7.4V 2A input requirement. I was thinking of using 18650 3.7V cells to power it or maybe 14500 cells for size constraints. And just as an addon: how about if I were to use NiMH AA Cells from something like Eneloop?

I'm not even going to pretend to know anything about circuits and stuff. I wanna know if I would need anything special or it's just a matter of connecting cables?

Comment: Given that it uses a LiIon battery internally the 7.4V input should accept either a  compatible power pack OR 2 x LiIon cells in series. Either 18650 or 14500 LiIon cells will work. Keep leads short and use suitably thick wiring. DO NOT solder to batteries. || 4 x AA Alkaline would work - but would almost certainly be substantially less suitable than LiIon cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it uses a 2 series LiIon cells LP-E12 LiIon battery internally the 7.4V input should accept either a  compatible power pack OR 2 x LiIon cells in series.
Either 18650 or 14500 LiIon cells will work.

Keep leads short and use suitably thick wiring.
DO NOT solder to batteries directly.
(Use tabbed cells or spot weld).

4 x AA Alkaline would work - but would almost certainly be substantially less suitable than LiIon cells.  2 x LiIon has a Vminimum of about 6V. 4 x Alkaline at 6V = 1.5V/cell = hardly discharged. Below that the camera may work, or may not.

Typical only ad for LP-E12 [here](https://www.rubbermonkey.co.nz/Canon-LP-E12-Lithium-Ion-Battery-Pack-7-2V-875mAh)

Canon LP-E12 Lithium-Ion Battery Pack (7.2V, 875mAh)

[image]